# Regex Extract Characters inside WUB

Tags: javascript, python, c++, regex, perl

I want a regex that extracts all the words inside a "WUB" but didin't found any solution!
for example it would extract from 
`"WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB"`

the following strings (without the quotes) 
`["WE", "ARE", "THE", "CHAMPIONS"]`

here's what i've tried so far:

`((?:.(?!WUB))+)`
But it gives me the following output (from the example above):

```
['WUBW', 'WUBAR', 'WU', 'WUBTH', 'WUBCHAMPION', 'WUBM', 'WUBFRIEN', 'WUB']
```

Please help me more understand this problem

Comment: The construct you used is a corrupt temepered greedy token. You hoped to match any text but a sequence of chars, but it is not used for that, there is no such a construct in regex. TGT only matches any char, 0 or 1 or more occurrences, that does not start some sequence. Just split with `WUB` and remove empty items. Or, use `WUB(.*?)(?=WUB)` and get Group 1 values. Or `(?<=WUB).*?(?=WUB)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jkGHs/1)

Comment: Simple implementation of described above `$_ ne '' && push @result, $_ for split('WUB', $data);`.

Comment: None of the answers to the linked question answered the OP's question, so I reopened the question.

Comment: Please fix the tags to exclude the language you aren't using. (If you have a similar question for more than one language, post them as separate questions.)

Answer (score 3):

```perl
$str =~ / WUB \K (?:(?!WUB).)+ (?=WUB) /sxg
```

or

```perl
$str =~ / (?<=WUB) (?:(?!WUB).)+ (?=WUB) /sxg    # Probably slower.
```

Starting after `WUB`, without actually including the WUB in the match (`\K`), find one or more characters that aren't the start of `WUB`. Make sure it's followed by `WUB` (`(?=WUB)`).

---

If the string will always start and end with `WUB`, or if you don't mind getting the text before the first `WUB` and after the last `WUB`, the following is a lot clearer and surely faster:

```
grep length, split /WUB/, $str
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple REGEX-Expression without the look-ahead/look-behind assertions is:

```
 /WUB((?:[^W]|W[^U]|WU[^B])+)/g
```

This assumes, that the string tested ends with the WUB. If it doesn't, you either have to include a zero-with look-ahead assertion (?=WUB) to the end,

```
 /WUB((?:[^W]|W[^U]|WU[^B])+)(?=WUB)/g
```

or remove any characters behind the last WUB before using the regex.

```
 s/WUB(?:[^W]|W[^U]|WU[^B])+$/WUB/
```

.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $s = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";

print Dumper ([$s =~ /WUB((?:[^W]|W[^U]|WU[^B])+)/g]);
```

prints out:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'WE',
          'ARE',
          'THE',
          'CHAMPIONS',
          'MY',
          'FRIEND'
        ];
```

Comment: You are right. I assumed the string was "well-formed" as in the example. If it isn't, the easiest solution is to add a zero-with look-ahead assertion (?=WUB) to the end, or remove any characters behind the last WUB before using the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, using split:

```
my $str = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";

# grep is here to remove empty elements
my @list = grep length, split /WUB/, $str;
say Dumper\@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'WE',
          'ARE',
          'THE',
          'CHAMPIONS',
          'MY',
          'FRIEND'
        ];
```

**Benchmark:**

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";

my $count = -3;
cmpthese($count, {
    'match' => sub {
        my @list = $str =~  / WUB \K (?:(?!WUB).)+ (?=WUB) /sxg;
    },
    'split' => sub {
        my @list = grep length, split /WUB/, $str;
    },
});
```

**Output:**

```
          Rate match split
match  57806/s    --  -54%
split 126455/s  119%    --
```

Comment: This fails for `abcWUBdefWUBghi`, returning text not in between `WUB`. (I would have suggested `grep length, split /WUB/, $str` if the OP hadn't explicitly specified they wanted text bewteen `WUB`)

Comment: To put the numbers into perspective, the match approach is 1/55486 s - 1/99924 s = 8 microseconds slower than the split approach.

Comment: If you use split you can simply remove the first and the last entry of the results.

Comment: @GeorgMavridis: That's what I've done, but it didn't work if the string doesn't begin with `WUB`.